# Vue loader error when building application on server

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, babel-loader, vue-loader

I have an application that uses Vue.js and builds with webpack and vue-loader. I also have a automated deploy proccess that worked 2 hours ago, but now doesn't work anymore (with the same exact source code).

The following errors seems to be provenient from the vue-loader, since it only prompt that message for js-compiled-from-vue files.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-00b26bea","hasScoped":false,"transformToRequire":{"video":["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/ProductCheckoutPage/PaymentForm.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:8662)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| var render = function () {var _vm=this;var _h=_vm.$createElement;var _c=_vm._self._c||_h;return _c('div',[(_vm.product.trial_days > 0 || (_vm.is_coupon_simulated && _vm.coupon.trial_days > 0))?_c('div',{staticClass:"subtitle is-size-3"},[_c('span',{domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.title-trial'))}}),_vm._v(" "),_c('strong',[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.title-trial-ends-at'))+_vm._s(_vm._f("moment")(_vm._f("moment")(new Date(),"add", ((_vm.product.trial_days) + " days")),'DD/MM/YYYY')))])]):_c('div',{staticClass:"subtitle is-size-3",domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.title'))}}),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"subtitle is-size-4 has-text-grey-light"},[_vm._v("\n    "+_vm._s(_vm.product.trial_days > 0 || (_vm.is_coupon_simulated && _vm.coupon.trial_days > 0) ? _vm.$t('payment-form.subtitle-trial') :_vm.$t('payment-form.subtitle'))+"\n  ")]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"payment-methods-options"},[_c('div',{staticClass:"buttons-list has-text-left"},_vm._l((_vm.available_payment_methods(_vm.product)),function(paymentMethod){return _c('a',{key:paymentMethod.id,staticClass:"button is-large has-icons-left is-fullwidth",class:{'is-primary': _vm.payment_method_id === paymentMethod.id},attrs:{"disabled":_vm.payment_method_id === paymentMethod.id},on:{"click":function($event){return _vm.onSelectPaymentMethod(paymentMethod.id)}}},[_c('span',{staticClass:"icon is-large"},[_c('font-awesome-icon',{attrs:{"icon":paymentMethod.icon}})],1),_vm._v(" "),_c('span',[_vm._v("\n          "+_vm._s(paymentMethod.label)+"\n        ")])])}),0),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.product.payment_observations)}})]),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.payment_method_id === _vm.paypal_id)?_c('form',{attrs:{"id":"checkout_payment_form","action":"","method":"post"},on:{"submit":function($event){$event.preventDefault();return _vm.onSubmitPaypalForm($event)}}},[_c('div',{staticClass:"subtitle is-size-3",domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.paypal.title'))}}),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"subtitle is-size-6 has-text-grey-light",domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.paypal.subtitle'))}}),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"field"},[_c('label',{staticClass:"label",attrs:{"for":""}},[_vm._v("Telefone")]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"control"},[_c('vue-tel-input',{attrs:{"required":true,"placeholder":_vm.$t('identification-form.fields.phone_number'),"autocomplete":"tel-national","preferredCountries":['br']},on:{"onInput":_vm.onPhoneInput},model:{value:(_vm.phone_input),callback:function ($$v) {_vm.phone_input=$$v},expression:"phone_input"}})],1),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.form.errors.has('phone_country_code'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.form.errors.get('phone_country_code'))}}):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.form.errors.has('phone_local_code'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.form.errors.get('phone_local_code'))}}):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.form.errors.has('phone_number'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.form.errors.get('phone_number'))}}):_vm._e()]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"content"},[_c('p',{staticClass:"is-size-7 has-text-grey has-text-justified",domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.advise.p1', {terms_url: _vm.terms_url, terms2_url: _vm.terms2_url}))}}),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.product.trial_days > 0)?_c('p',{staticClass:"is-size-7 has-text-grey has-text-justified",domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.advise.p2', {publisher_name: _vm.product.publisher_founder.name, product_name: _vm.product.name, product_price: ("R$ " + (_vm.format_price(_vm.product.price)) + " / " + _vm.human_period)}))}}):_vm._e()]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"control has-text-centered"},[_c('button',{staticClass:"button is-large is-fullwidth is-primary",class:{'is-loading': _vm.is_creating_order},attrs:{"type":"submit"}},[(_vm.product.trial_days > 0 && !_vm.already_subscribed(_vm.product))?_c('span',[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.submit_with_trial')))]):_c('span',[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.submit')))])])])]):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.payment_method_id === _vm.boleto_id)?_c('form',{attrs:{"id":"checkout_payment_form","action":"","method":"post"},on:{"submit":function($event){$event.preventDefault();return _vm.onSubmitBoletoForm($event)}}},[_c('div',{staticClass:"subtitle is-size-3",domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.billet.title'))}}),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"subtitle is-size-6 has-text-grey-light",domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.billet.subtitle'))}}),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"field"},[_c('label',{staticClass:"label",attrs:{"for":""}},[_vm._v("Telefone")]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"control"},[_c('vue-tel-input',{attrs:{"required":true,"placeholder":_vm.$t('identification-form.fields.phone_number'),"autocomplete":"tel-national","preferredCountries":['br']},on:{"onInput":_vm.onPhoneInput},model:{value:(_vm.phone_input),callback:function ($$v) {_vm.phone_input=$$v},expression:"phone_input"}})],1),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.form.errors.has('phone_country_code'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.form.errors.get('phone_country_code'))}}):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.form.errors.has('phone_local_code'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.form.errors.get('phone_local_code'))}}):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.form.errors.has('phone_number'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.form.errors.get('phone_number'))}}):_vm._e()]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"content"},[_c('p',{staticClass:"is-size-7 has-text-grey has-text-justified",domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.advise.p1', {terms_url: _vm.terms_url, terms2_url: _vm.terms2_url}))}}),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.product.trial_days > 0)?_c('p',{staticClass:"is-size-7 has-text-grey has-text-justified",domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.advise.p2', {publisher_name: _vm.product.publisher_founder.name, product_name: _vm.product.name, product_price: ("R$ " + (_vm.format_price(_vm.product.price)) + " / " + _vm.human_period)}))}}):_vm._e()]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"control has-text-centered"},[_c('button',{staticClass:"button is-large is-fullwidth is-primary",class:{'is-loading': _vm.is_creating_order},attrs:{"type":"submit"}},[(_vm.product.trial_days > 0 && !_vm.already_subscribed(_vm.product))?_c('span',[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.submit_with_trial')))]):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.product.is_recurring && _vm.product.trial_days <= 0)?_c('span',[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.submit')))]):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(!_vm.product.is_recurring && _vm.product.trial_days <= 0)?_c('span',[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.submit-pay-with-billet')))]):_vm._e()])])]):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.payment_method_id === _vm.credit_card_id)?_c('form',{attrs:{"id":"checkout_payment_form","action":"","method":"post"},on:{"submit":function($event){$event.preventDefault();return _vm.onSubmitCreditCardForm($event)}}},[_c('div',{staticClass:"subtitle is-size-3",domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.credit-card.title'))}}),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"subtitle is-size-6 has-text-grey-light"},[_vm._v("\n      "+_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.credit-card.subtitle'))+"\n    ")]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"columns is-multiline"},[_vm._m(0),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"column is-12"},[_c('label',{staticClass:"label",class:{ 'has-text-danger': _vm.card_form.errors.has(['card_number']) }},[_vm._v("\n          "+_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.fields.card_number'))+"\n        ")]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"field has-addons",attrs:{"tabindex":"1"}},[_c('div',{staticClass:"control has-icons-left card-number",on:{"keydown":function($event){return _vm.card_form.errors.clear('card_number')}}},[_c('div',{staticClass:"icon is-small is-left"},[_c('vue-material-icon',{attrs:{"name":"credit_card"}})],1),_vm._v(" "),_c('input',{directives:[{name:"mask",rawName:"v-mask",value:('#### #### #### ####'),expression:"'#### #### #### ####'"},{name:"model",rawName:"v-model",value:(_vm.card_form.card_number),expression:"card_form.card_number"}],staticClass:"input",class:{'is-danger': _vm.card_form.errors.has('card_number')},attrs:{"type":"text","placeholder":_vm.$t('payment-form.placeholders.card_number'),"name":"card_number","autocomplete":"cc-number"},domProps:{"value":(_vm.card_form.card_number)},on:{"input":function($event){if($event.target.composing){ return;_vm.$set(_vm.card_form, "card_number", $event.target.value)}}})]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"control card-expiration"},[_c('input',{directives:[{name:"model",rawName:"v-model",value:(_vm.card_form.card_expiration_date),expression:"card_form.card_expiration_date"}],staticClass:"input",attrs:{"type":"text","placeholder":_vm.$t('payment-form.placeholders.card_expiration_date'),"name":"card_expiration_date","autocomplete":"cc-exp"},domProps:{"value":(_vm.card_form.card_expiration_date)},on:{"input":function($event){if($event.target.composing){ return;_vm.$set(_vm.card_form, "card_expiration_date", $event.target.value)}}})]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"control is-2 card-cvv"},[_c('input',{directives:[{name:"model",rawName:"v-model",value:(_vm.card_form.card_cvv),expression:"card_form.card_cvv"}],staticClass:"input",attrs:{"type":"text","placeholder":_vm.$t('payment-form.placeholders.card_cvv'),"name":"card_cvv","autocomplete":"cc-csc"},domProps:{"value":(_vm.card_form.card_cvv)},on:{"input":function($event){if($event.target.composing){ return;_vm.$set(_vm.card_form, "card_cvv", $event.target.value)}}})])]),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.card_form.errors.has('card_number'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.card_form.errors.get('card_number'))}}):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.card_form.errors.has('card_expiration_date'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.card_form.errors.get('card_expiration_date'))}}):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.card_form.errors.has('card_expiration_month'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.card_form.errors.get('card_expiration_month'))}}):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.card_form.errors.has('card_expiration_year'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.card_form.errors.get('card_expiration_year'))}}):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.card_form.errors.has('card_cvv'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.card_form.errors.get('card_cvv'))}}):_vm._e()]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"column is-12"},[_c('form-control',{attrs:{"form":_vm.card_form,"name":"card_holder_name","label":_vm.$t('payment-form.fields.card_holder_name'),"control-class":"has-icons-left"}},[_c('input',{directives:[{name:"model",rawName:"v-model",value:(_vm.card_form.card_holder_name),expression:"card_form.card_holder_name"}],staticClass:"input",attrs:{"type":"text","placeholder":_vm.$t('payment-form.placeholders.card_holder_name'),"autocomplete":"cc-name","name":"card_holder_name"},domProps:{"value":(_vm.card_form.card_holder_name)},on:{"input":function($event){if($event.target.composing){ return;_vm.$set(_vm.card_form, "card_holder_name", $event.target.value)}}}),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"icon is-small is-left"},[_c('vue-material-icon',{attrs:{"name":"account_circle"}})],1)]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"field"},[_c('label',{staticClass:"label",attrs:{"for":""}},[_vm._v("Telefone")]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"control"},[_c('vue-tel-input',{attrs:{"required":true,"placeholder":_vm.$t('identification-form.fields.phone_number'),"autocomplete":"tel-national","preferredCountries":['br']},on:{"onInput":_vm.onPhoneInput},model:{value:(_vm.phone_input),callback:function ($$v) {_vm.phone_input=$$v},expression:"phone_input"}})],1),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.form.errors.has('phone_country_code'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.form.errors.get('phone_country_code'))}}):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.form.errors.has('phone_local_code'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.form.errors.get('phone_local_code'))}}):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.form.errors.has('phone_number'))?_c('p',{staticClass:"help is-danger",domProps:{"textContent":_vm._s(_vm.form.errors.get('phone_number'))}}):_vm._e()])],1),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"column is-12"},[_c('div',{staticClass:"content"},[_c('p',{staticClass:"is-size-7 has-text-grey has-text-justified",domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.advise.p1', {terms_url: _vm.terms_url, terms2_url: _vm.terms2_url}))}}),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.product.trial_days > 0)?_c('p',{staticClass:"is-size-7 has-text-grey has-text-justified",domProps:{"innerHTML":_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.advise.p2', {publisher_name: _vm.product.publisher_founder.name, product_name: _vm.product.name, product_price: ("R$ " + (_vm.format_price(_vm.product.price)) + " / " + _vm.human_period)}))}}):_vm._e()]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"control has-text-centered"},[_c('button',{staticClass:"button is-large is-fullwidth is-primary",class:{'is-loading': _vm.form.sendingData || _vm.is_creating_order},attrs:{"type":"submit"}},[(_vm.product.trial_days > 0 && !_vm.already_subscribed(_vm.product))?_c('span',[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.submit_with_trial')))]):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(_vm.product.is_recurring && _vm.already_subscribed(_vm.product))?_c('span',[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.submit')))]):_vm._e(),_vm._v(" "),(!_vm.product.is_recurring && _vm.product.trial_days <= 0)?_c('span',[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t('payment-form.submit-pay-with-cc')))]):_vm._e()])])]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"column is-12 ssl-certifications"})])]):_vm._e()])}
| var staticRenderFns = [function () {var _vm=this;var _h=_vm.$createElement;var _c=_vm._self._c||_h;return _c('div',{staticClass:"column is-12 has-text-centered"},[_c('div',{staticClass:"card-wrap"})])}]
| var esExports = { render: render, staticRenderFns: staticRenderFns }
 @ ./src/components/ProductCheckoutPage/PaymentForm.vue 9:0-374
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/ProductCheckoutPage.vue
 @ ./src/components/ProductCheckoutPage.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-2654dcc4","hasScoped":false,"transformToRequire":{"video":["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/Login.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:984)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| var render = function () {var _vm=this;var _h=_vm.$createElement;var _c=_vm._self._c||_h;return _c('div',{staticClass:"login"},[_c('div',{staticClass:"container has-text-centered"},[_c('div',{staticClass:"column is-4 is-offset-4"},[_c('div',{staticClass:"box"},[_c('form',{attrs:{"method":"POST","action":""},on:{"submit":function($event){$event.preventDefault();return _vm.onSubmitLoginForm()}}},[_c('p',{staticClass:"has-text-centered subtitle"},[_vm._v("Acessar a plataforma")]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"field"},[_c('div',{staticClass:"control"},[_c('input',{directives:[{name:"model",rawName:"v-model",value:(_vm.credentials.email),expression:"credentials.email"}],staticClass:"input is-medium",attrs:{"autocomplete":"email","type":"email","placeholder":_vm.$t('login.fields.your_email'),"autofocus":""},domProps:{"value":(_vm.credentials.email)},on:{"input":function($event){if($event.target.composing){ return;_vm.$set(_vm.credentials, "email", $event.target.value)}}})])]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"field"},[_c('div',{staticClass:"control"},[_c('input',{directives:[{name:"model",rawName:"v-model",value:(_vm.credentials.password),expression:"credentials.password"}],staticClass:"input is-medium",attrs:{"type":"password","placeholder":_vm.$t('login.fields.your_password')},domProps:{"value":(_vm.credentials.password)},on:{"input":function($event){if($event.target.composing){ return;_vm.$set(_vm.credentials, "password", $event.target.value)}}})])]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"field"},[_c('label',{staticClass:"checkbox"},[_c('input',{directives:[{name:"model",rawName:"v-model",value:(_vm.credentials.remember_me),expression:"credentials.remember_me"}],attrs:{"type":"checkbox","name":"remember_me","value":"1"},domProps:{"checked":Array.isArray(_vm.credentials.remember_me)?_vm._i(_vm.credentials.remember_me,"1")>-1:(_vm.credentials.remember_me)},on:{"change":function($event){var $$a=_vm.credentials.remember_me,$$el=$event.target,$$c=$$el.checked?(true):(false);if(Array.isArray($$a)){var $$v="1",$$i=_vm._i($$a,$$v);if($$el.checked){$$i<0&&(_vm.$set(_vm.credentials, "remember_me", $$a.concat([$$v])))}else{$$i>-1&&(_vm.$set(_vm.credentials, "remember_me", $$a.slice(0,$$i).concat($$a.slice($$i+1))))}}else{_vm.$set(_vm.credentials, "remember_me", $$c)}}}}),_vm._v("\n                          "+_vm._s(_vm.$t('login.fields.remember_me'))+"\n                        ")])]),_vm._v(" "),_c('button',{staticClass:"button is-primary is-block is-medium is-fullwidth",class:{'is-loading': _vm.sendingData},attrs:{"type":"submit"}},[_vm._v("\n                        "+_vm._s(_vm.$t('login.buttons.sign_in'))+"\n                      ")]),_vm._v(" "),_c('p',[_c('br'),_vm._v(" "),_c('router-link',{attrs:{"to":"/forgot-password"}},[_c('a',{attrs:{"href":"../"}},[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t('login.buttons.forgot_my_password')))])])],1)])]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"is-divider",attrs:{"data-content":"OU"}}),_vm._v(" "),_c('router-link',{staticClass:"button is-secondary is-block is-large is-fullwidth",attrs:{"to":"/signup"}},[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t('login.buttons.sign_up')))])],1)])])}
| var staticRenderFns = []
| var esExports = { render: render, staticRenderFns: staticRenderFns }
 @ ./src/components/Login.vue 9:0-362
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-8e44c18a","hasScoped":false,"transformToRequire":{"video":["src","poster"],"source":"src","img":"src","image":"xlink:href"},"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/Instagram/CreateProfileForm.vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:992)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| var render = function () {var _vm=this;var _h=_vm.$createElement;var _c=_vm._self._c||_h;return _c('form',{attrs:{"action":"","method":"post"},on:{"submit":function($event){$event.preventDefault();return _vm.onSubmitForm($event)}}},[_c('div',{staticClass:"columns is-multiline"},[_vm._m(0),_vm._v(" "),_vm._m(1),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"column is-12"},[_c('div',{staticClass:"content"},[_c('p',[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t("instagram.form.instruction")))])])]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"column is-12"},[_c('form-control',{attrs:{"form":_vm.form,"name":"username","control-class":"has-icons-left"}},[_c('input',{directives:[{name:"model",rawName:"v-model",value:(_vm.form.username),expression:"form.username"}],staticClass:"input",attrs:{"type":"username","placeholder":_vm.$t('instagram.form.username'),"name":"username"},domProps:{"value":(_vm.form.username)},on:{"input":function($event){if($event.target.composing){ return;_vm.$set(_vm.form, "username", $event.target.value)}}}),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"icon is-small is-left"},[_c('vue-material-icon',{attrs:{"name":"account_circle"}})],1)]),_vm._v(" "),_c('form-control',{attrs:{"form":_vm.form,"name":"password","control-class":"has-icons-left"}},[_c('input',{directives:[{name:"model",rawName:"v-model",value:(_vm.form.password),expression:"form.password"}],staticClass:"input",attrs:{"type":"password","placeholder":_vm.$t('instagram.form.password'),"name":"password"},domProps:{"value":(_vm.form.password)},on:{"input":function($event){if($event.target.composing){ return;_vm.$set(_vm.form, "password", $event.target.value)}}}),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"icon is-small is-left"},[_c('vue-material-icon',{attrs:{"name":"lock"}})],1)]),_vm._v(" "),_c('form-control',{attrs:{"form":_vm.form,"name":"password_confirmation","control-class":"has-icons-left"}},[_c('input',{directives:[{name:"model",rawName:"v-model",value:(_vm.form.password_confirmation),expression:"form.password_confirmation"}],staticClass:"input",attrs:{"type":"password","placeholder":_vm.$t('instagram.form.password_confirmation'),"name":"password_confirmation"},domProps:{"value":(_vm.form.password_confirmation)},on:{"input":function($event){if($event.target.composing){ return;_vm.$set(_vm.form, "password_confirmation", $event.target.value)}}}),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"icon is-small is-left"},[_c('vue-material-icon',{attrs:{"name":"lock"}})],1)])],1),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"column is-12"},[_c('div',{staticClass:"control has-text-centered"},[_c('button',{staticClass:"button is-primary",class:{'is-loading': _vm.form.sendingData},attrs:{"type":"submit"}},[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t('instagram.form.submit')))])])]),_vm._v(" "),_c('div',{staticClass:"column is-12"},[_c('div',{staticClass:"content"},[_c('p',{staticClass:"has-text-centered"},[_c('a',{attrs:{"href":"https://www.instagram.com/accounts/password/reset/","target":"_blank"}},[_vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.$t('instagram.forgot-password')))])])])])])])}
| var staticRenderFns = [function () {var _vm=this;var _h=_vm.$createElement;var _c=_vm._self._c||_h;return _c('div',{staticClass:"column is-12 has-text-centered"},[_c('div',{staticClass:"notification is-primary"},[_vm._v("\n        Você deve deixar apenas "),_c('strong',[_vm._v("1 dispositivo")]),_vm._v(" conectado a sua conta do Instagram!\n      ")])])},function () {var _vm=this;var _h=_vm.$createElement;var _c=_vm._self._c||_h;return _c('div',{staticClass:"column is-12 has-text-centered"},[_c('img',{staticClass:"logo-instagram",attrs:{"src":"/static/logo-instagram.png","alt":"Instagram"}})])}]
| var esExports = { render: render, staticRenderFns: staticRenderFns }
 @ ./src/components/Instagram/CreateProfileForm.vue 9:0-380
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Instagram.vue
 @ ./src/components/Instagram.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js

  Build failed with errors.
```

Anyone is experiencing or have already experienced an error like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. I think they messed up a release.

Comment: @pubkey you mean the vue-loader folks?